# How to list all proprietary (license field) snap packages installed on my box?

Tags: snap, license

After a `snap` has been installed with `sudo snap install [package]` how can I list all packages on my box which have a proprietary license? For deciding what is Open Source and what not I like [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Free_Software_Guidelines).

For example [spotify](https://snapcraft.io/spotify)

```
Details for Spotify
License
    Proprietary
```

Comment: I'm surprised there's NOTHING about this anywhere online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all snap packages:

```
snap list
```

To get details (including the license):

```
snap info <package name>
```

So something as

```
for p in $(snap list | awk 'NR > 1 { print $1 }') ; do
    snap info $p | grep license
done
```

would list the license for each snap, and then you could filter that at will.
Now, the parameter `license` in the few snaps I have is `unset`.
Except for `snapd`, which has `GPL-3.0`, versus `GPL-3.0+` shown [here](https://snapcraft.io/snapd).

So, apparently, to get the actual license for each snap you would have to write a script that retrieves the info from `https://snapcraft.io/<package name>`, or, better, from `snap info <package name> | grep store-url` (likely the same in all cases, but I would not bet on it).
Not a big deal, but not expected either probably.

Adding a script [as commented by @Xosrov](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278305/how-to-list-all-proprietary-license-field-snap-packages-installed-on-my-box#comment2259882_1325744)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in $(snap list | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}') ; do
  url="https://snapcraft.io/${i}"
  echo "${url}"
  site=$(curl -s "${url}")
  for j in $site ; do
    res=$(echo "$j" | awk -F'>' '$0~"data-live=\"license"{print $2}')
    if [ -n "$res" ] ; then
      echo "License for ${i}: ${res:0:$((${#string}-4))}"
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Thats what i found too! ```snap info``` doesn't show license for Spotify for example. I managed to write some bash to get the info from the site directly(it's pretty slow though since i suck at bash): ```for i in $(snap list | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}'); do site=$(curl -s "https://snapcraft.io/${i}"); for j in $site; do  res=$(echo $j | awk -F'>' '$0~"data-live=\"license"{print $2}'); if [ ! -z "$res" ]; then echo "License for ${i}: ${res:0:$((${#string}-4))}"; break; fi; done; done
```

Comment: I'd still love to see a better method though, if nobody else answers i'll just give you the bounty lol

Comment: @Xosrov - Your script takes ~1sec per snap, so I guess it is not that bad.